# RDLC Report add line between white space and last page

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

I'm working on a "contract format-like" rdlc report, which will have four tablix with variable numbers of rows. This report also have a fixed "last page" that is set to do a page break "always".
What I want to achieve is to "span" some element to gave the impression that the remaining white space between penultimate/before last and last page won't be written/added with any more info in the future (as we use to do by handwriting/completing, in the past). The ideal object could be a transversal line (I think that's not possible in my research). Also I have found some workarounds that take in count the "number of rows" of each tablix and do and approximation height, then add the "needed" rows to the end of the last tablix but that's not quite the solution I'm looking for.

Please look the attached image for a better idea of the line desired location:

[Explanation-Layout-And-Variable-Height-Meaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMmf7.png)

I hope you can advise with your experience on this (even if not the solution some idea of how to achieve it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something....

If you wan to simply add a page break and then a 'blank' page...

Just add a rectangle under your last tablix.
Make it short vertically, (the width does not really matter as long as it's no wider than you tablix). Move it so it's close to the last tablix (say 5pt below)

Right-click the rectable and choose properties. Now set the properties of the rectangle to "Add a page break before"

[image]

This will force a page break after the last tablix and then push the empty rectangle onto the next page giving the impression that it is blank.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for (probably I didn't explain properly). I don't want a "blank" page after the last tablix, I want to add a line in the remaining space between the last tablix and the final page. That's why I'm talking about "variable space" to span into.

Comment: Ah OK I see now. Not sure of the top of my head how you could so that as I don't think size properties take expressions but that might be worth looking into.